# How to update a xcode project to Cocos2d- 2.0

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I just downloaded cocos2d~2.0 and I'm having trouble figuring out how to start a new Xcode project using the cocos2d~2.0. I can't open the read me file in the download either. Could someone who's done this give me step-by-step help?

Comment: Is the download broken? Have you tried using cocos2d with Kobold2D? http://www.kobold2d.com … Just install and everything is ready to go.

Comment: I've seen Kobold2D. The download isn;t broken, I just don't have the proper application to open the 'read me' file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try following the migration guide on the cocos2d site? http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0